# How to create celery worker with python code (not command line)?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

In my code in file **tasks.py** I create celery app object (RabbitMQ broker service is downloaded and running):

```
app = Celery('tasks', include=['tasks'], broker='amqp://localhost')
```

Then in the same file define multiple tasks that I will be sending to the worker, like that:

```
@app.task
def task(arg):
    print(arg)
```

And define function for starting worker:

```
def celery_start_worker():
    worker = app.Worker(
        include=['tasks']
    )
    worker.start()
```

In main file of my project I call `celery_start_worker()`:

```
from tasks import celery_start_worker
from threading import Thread

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target=celery_start_worker)
    thread.start()
```

And here arises an **error**:

```
-------------- celery@DESKTOP-F77818V v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0 2023-07-20 10:34:10
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x1f0e4149910
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[2023-07-20 10:34:10,953: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py:498: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2023-07-20 10:34:11,004: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py:498: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2023-07-20 10:34:11,508: WARNING/MainProcess] Updates were skipped successfully.
[2023-07-20 10:34:12,377: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\kombu\pidbox.py:72: UserWarning: A node named celery@DESKTOP-F77818V is already using this process mailbox!

Maybe you forgot to shutdown the other node or did not do so properly?
Or if you meant to start multiple nodes on the same host please make sure
you give each node a unique node name!

  warnings.warn(W_PIDBOX_IN_USE.format(node=self))

[2023-07-20 10:34:15,311: WARNING/MainProcess] Goodbye!
```

**My question: what is causing the error and how do I fix it?**

Comment: Can you share the output after specifying DEBUG as the logging level, while starting worker like this => `worker = app.Worker(include=['tasks'], loglevel ='DEBUG')`. I use ubuntu and I can tell that it's just a WARNING. Worker doesn't shutdown because of duplicate nodename